# Load mapbox once with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox-gl

I am currently designing an app that uses the same map-box map on two different pages. When I navigate to each page the map reloads each time. Currently this is a rather big issue because the map takes a very long time to load as I am displaying a lot of heat map data onto it.

Is there a way to make sure the map stays loaded while navigating between the two pages?

I've started exploring state management, but I'm not sure that's a solution to the problem and I'm still not exactly sure what that's accomplishing.

Comment: Is the `map-box` inside `router-outlet` or outside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the RouteReuseStrategy, as mentionned here: https://itnext.io/cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-3e4c8b174d5f

Create a service cache-route-reuse.strategy.ts:

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router/';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';
export class CacheRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    storedRouteHandles = new Map<string, DetachedRouteHandle>();

    allowRetrieveCache = {
        'mapbox': true
    };

    shouldReuseRoute(before: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        if (this.getPath(before) === 'the-path-of-the-first-component' && this.getPath(curr) === 'the-path-of-the-second-component') {
            this.allowRetrieveCache['mapbox'] = true;
        } else {
            this.allowRetrieveCache['mapbox'] = false;
        }

        return before.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
        return this.storedRouteHandles.get(this.getPath(route)) as DetachedRouteHandle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        const path = this.getPath(route);
        if (this.allowRetrieveCache[path]) {
            return this.storedRouteHandles.has(this.getPath(route));
        }

        return false;
    }

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        const path = this.getPath(route);
        if (this.allowRetrieveCache.hasOwnProperty(path)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        this.storedRouteHandles.set(this.getPath(route), detachedTree);
    }

    private getPath(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        if (route.routeConfig !== null && route.routeConfig.path !== null) {
            return route.routeConfig.path;
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

And then register it in your app.module.ts:

```
...
providers: [{
  provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
  useClass: CacheRouteReuseStrategy
}],
...
```

You may want to adapt the behavior of the shouldReuseRoute method (for instance I believe it would work when navigating to map2 from map1, but not the other way).